# Why aren't my Angular 6 buttons rippling?

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

lately I have been coding the frontend of my application. I have been utilizing Angular 6 to build it, but I have noticed a small deviation in my buttons. They darken when you hover over them, but they do not have any ripple effect when you click them. Here is my app.module.ts.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {
  MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatSelectModule, MatTableModule, MatGridListModule,
  MatCardModule, MatMenuModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatOptionModule
} from '@angular/material';
import { PlaceholderComponent } from './placeholder/placeholder.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import {HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import 'hammerjs';




const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'placeholder', component: PlaceholderComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PlaceholderComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes ),
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatOptionModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatOptionModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.css

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
.divider {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mat-card {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}

.demo-toolbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

mat-card {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

mat-toolbar-row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.done {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.content-center {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

And here's my app.component.html.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span> A store</span>
  <span class="demo-toolbar"></span>
  <button mat-button color="accent">Register</button>
  <span class="divider"></span>
  <button mat-button >Login</button>
  <span class="divider"></span>
  <button mat-button>See your profile now!</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-card>
  <span>
    This is a shop.
    Login or register above!
  </span>
</mat-card>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ClothAppFrontEnd</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

[My Angular site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NESF.png)
The index.html
I unfortunately don't see what could be wrong. I've imported the theme, and I've linked the Material Icons from Google in my index.html. Help is gratefully accepted.

Hi. Here is the MCV example in StackBlitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xiapvj

Comment: Please create an [mcve], I recommend using https://stackblitz.com, and post the link in your question.

Comment: I've added the MCV example. @Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all weary visitors, it was a surreptious oversight that had eluded me. I merely missed importing my theme in my styles.css class, and I will upload my MCV example today. One must always be vigilant for the little oversights!

styles.css(before)
(It was empty.)

styles.css(after)

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's `:hover` action of Angular Material buttons, `mat-button`. See its official `mat-button` example on https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview, there would be a`<div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>`in the `<button>` tag under `<span>` tag if hovering the cursor over the button. It's the `mat-button-ripple` that caused the `:hover` effect.

After knowing the reason of the rippling, you could try many ways to override the styling. An extreme way is to use `::ng-deep` combinator to override `mat-button-ripple` on the specific page.

**Edits on July 31:**
I made a mistake. It's another element `<div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>`that caused this effect. The style of `.mat-button-focus-overlay` is `background-color: rgba(255,215,64,.12);`

To fix your styling with a `::ng-deep` combinator, add this style to the component styling file `app.component.css`.

```
::ng-deep .mat-button.mat-accent .mat-button-focus-overlay, 
.mat-icon-button.mat-accent .mat-button-focus-overlay, 
.mat-stroked-button.mat-accent .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: HI, @T.Liu, how would you use the ::ng-deep combinator to override mat-button-ripple on the page? I am a neophyte and picked up on Angular a few days ago. I also attempted to apply the div inside the button but it completely removed the button. Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Melcalc , I added a quick fix in my original answer. Hope it can help.

Comment: Hi, @T.Liu, I have solved the problem(my global styles.css did not have the material styling). I appreciate your help on the ::ng-deep comvinator, it's something I wouldn't have created myself. I have moved on to other Angular problems, unfortunately.